# How to update state when button from another file is triggered

Tags: flutter

I'm new in Flutter I want to update _totalAmount in main.dart file whenever Icon button from CardDesign.dart is pressed, Like when pressing - button totalAmount decreases and when pressing + button totalAmount increases.

I searched on the internet but couldn't find an answer that fits my problem.

main.dart file code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'CardDesign.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyMaterialApp());
}

class MyMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMaterialApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Metropolis',
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _totalAmount = 0;

  List itemList = [
    CardDesign(
      itemTitle: "Pullover",
      itemColor: "Black",
      itemSize: "L",
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemPrice: 51,
      itemUrl: "assets/images/pullover.png",
    ),
    CardDesign(
      itemTitle: "T-Shirt",
      itemColor: "Gray",
      itemSize: "L",
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemPrice: 30,
      itemUrl: "assets/images/t_shirt.png",
    ),
    CardDesign(
      itemTitle: "Sport Dress",
      itemColor: "Black",
      itemSize: "M",
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemPrice: 43,
      itemUrl: "assets/images/sport_dress.png",
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Icon(Icons.search, size: 25),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "My Bag",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => itemList[index],
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                        height: 15,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                  itemCount: itemList.length),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Total amount",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Text(
                  "${_totalAmount}\$",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text("Congratulation!"),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                  ));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "CHECK OUT",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CardDesign.dart code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  final itemTitle, itemColor, itemSize, itemUrl;
  int itemQuantity, showPrice = 0, itemPrice;

  CardDesign({
    super.key,
    required this.itemTitle,
    required this.itemColor,
    required this.itemSize,
    required this.itemQuantity,
    required this.itemPrice,
    required this.itemUrl,
  });

  @override
  State<CardDesign> createState() => _CardDesignState();
}

class _CardDesignState extends State<CardDesign> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 136,
      child: Card(
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 2,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    widget.itemUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment:
                      //     MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "${widget.itemTitle}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.more_vert_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 28,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(text: "Color: "),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: "${widget.itemColor}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(text: "Size: "),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: "${widget.itemSize}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (widget.itemQuantity > 0) {
                                  widget.itemQuantity--;
                                  widget.showPrice -= widget.itemPrice;
                                  setState(() {});
                                }
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.remove_rounded),
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              style: IconButton.styleFrom(
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shadowColor: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                              child: Text(
                                "${widget.itemQuantity}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black54),
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                widget.itemQuantity++;
                                widget.showPrice += widget.itemPrice;
                                if (widget.itemQuantity == 5) {
                                  showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                      surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      title: Text(
                                        "Congratulations!",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                      ),
                                      content: Text(
                                        "You have added \n5\n${widget.itemTitle} on your bag!",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                      actions: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            },
                                            child: Text(
                                              "OKAY",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add_rounded),
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              style: IconButton.styleFrom(
                                  elevation: 2,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shadowColor: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                          child: Text(
                            "${widget.showPrice}\$",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I'm new in flutter I want to update _totalAmount in main.dart file whenever Icon button from CardDesign.dart is pressed.

Comment: A common approach is to use [state management](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt)

Answer (score 0):

Like said above a state management solution would be the safest approach, using provider or riverpod, for example. Or you can create a new input on your CardDesign widget that would be a function with a value.

Main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'CardDesign.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyMaterialApp());
}

class MyMaterialApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyMaterialApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        fontFamily: 'Metropolis',
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
      ),
      home: MyApp(),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _totalAmount = 0;

  // New Function
  addToCart(bool add) {
    setState(() { // Need set state here to have the change in value reflected on the ui after causing a rerender.
      add ? _totalAmount++ : _totalAmount--; // Terenary used to support the feature of removing from the total amount or any other type of logic you want, and the inputs passed to the Card Design can be cahnged as well.
    })
  }

  List itemList = [
    CardDesign(
      itemTitle: "Pullover",
      itemColor: "Black",
      itemSize: "L",
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemPrice: 51,
      itemUrl: "assets/images/pullover.png",
      addToCart: (value) => addToCart(value)
    ),
    CardDesign(
      itemTitle: "T-Shirt",
      itemColor: "Gray",
      itemSize: "L",
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemPrice: 30,
      itemUrl: "assets/images/t_shirt.png",
      addToCart: (value) => addToCart(value)
    ),
    CardDesign(
      itemTitle: "Sport Dress",
      itemColor: "Black",
      itemSize: "M",
      itemQuantity: 0,
      itemPrice: 43,
      itemUrl: "assets/images/sport_dress.png",
      addToCart: (value) => addToCart(value)
    ),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(249, 249, 249, 1),
        actions: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
            child: Icon(Icons.search, size: 25),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Text(
              "My Bag",
              style: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 32,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.separated(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) => itemList[index],
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                        height: 15,
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                  itemCount: itemList.length),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Total amount",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 15,
                      color: Colors.black54,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                ),
                Spacer(),
                Text(
                  "${_totalAmount}\$",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                )
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                    content: Text("Congratulation!"),
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 1500),
                  ));
                },
                child: Text(
                  "CHECK OUT",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

CardDesign.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CardDesign extends StatefulWidget {
  final itemTitle, itemColor, itemSize, itemUrl;
  int itemQuantity, showPrice = 0, itemPrice;
  final Function(bool) addToCart;

  CardDesign({
    super.key,
    required this.itemTitle,
    required this.itemColor,
    required this.itemSize,
    required this.itemQuantity,
    required this.itemPrice,
    required this.itemUrl,
    required this.addToCart,
  });

  @override
  State<CardDesign> createState() => _CardDesignState();
}

class _CardDesignState extends State<CardDesign> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 136,
      child: Card(
        surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
        color: Colors.white,
        elevation: 2,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3,
              child: SizedBox(
                height: double.infinity,
                child: ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    widget.itemUrl,
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(7),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Row(
                      // mainAxisAlignment:
                      //     MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                          "${widget.itemTitle}",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Icon(
                          Icons.more_vert_rounded,
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          size: 28,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: [
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(text: "Color: "),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: "${widget.itemColor}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 10,
                        ),
                        RichText(
                          text: TextSpan(
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.grey, fontSize: 16),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(text: "Size: "),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: "${widget.itemSize}",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.black54,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 14,
                    ),
                    Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                if (widget.itemQuantity > 0) {
                                  widget.addToCart(false); // Use of function
                                  widget.itemQuantity--;
                                  widget.showPrice -= widget.itemPrice;
                                  setState(() {});
                                }
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.remove_rounded),
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              style: IconButton.styleFrom(
                                  elevation: 3,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shadowColor: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding:
                                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
                              child: Text(
                                "${widget.itemQuantity}",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20, color: Colors.black54),
                              ),
                            ),
                            IconButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                widget.addToCart(true); // Use of function
                                widget.itemQuantity++;
                                widget.showPrice += widget.itemPrice;
                                if (widget.itemQuantity == 5) {
                                  showDialog(
                                    context: context,
                                    builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                                      surfaceTintColor: Colors.white,
                                      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                      title: Text(
                                        "Congratulations!",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                                      ),
                                      content: Text(
                                        "You have added \n5\n${widget.itemTitle} on your bag!",
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                      ),
                                      actions: [
                                        SizedBox(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          child: ElevatedButton(
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            },
                                            child: Text(
                                              "OKAY",
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                            ),
                                            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                                                backgroundColor: Colors.red),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }
                                setState(() {});
                              },
                              icon: Icon(Icons.add_rounded),
                              color: Colors.black54,
                              style: IconButton.styleFrom(
                                  elevation: 2,
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                  shadowColor: Colors.white),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 12),
                          child: Text(
                            "${widget.showPrice}\$",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 18),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: He said, he was new in flutter, please help his by more detail your code and don't use advance code

Comment: 50:31: Error: Can't access 'this' in a field initializer to read 'addToCart'.
        addToCart: (value) => addToCart(value)
@CStark
This error occurs when passing arguments to CardDesign

Screen shot -> https://ibb.co/6NmXfjq

Comment: hmm, maybe you cant have them be the same name